# Sending persisted JDO instances over GWT-RPC

Tags: gwt, jdo, gwt-rpc

I've just started learning Google Web Toolkit and finished writing the Stock Watcher tutorial app.

Is my thinking correct that **if one wants to persist a business object** (like a Stock) **using JDO and send it** back and forth to/from the client **over RPC then one has to create two separate classes for that object**: One with the JDO annotations for persisting it on the server and another which is serialisable and used over RPC?

I notice the Stock Watcher has separate classes and I can theorise why:

- Otherwise the gwt compiler would try
  to generate javascript for everything
  the persisted class referenced like
  JDO and com.google.blah.users.User, etc
- Also there may be logic on the server-side 
  class which doesn't apply to the client 
  and vice-versa.

I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. I don't want to have to create two versions of all my business object classes which I want to use over RPC *if I don't have to*.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: **you don't need to create duplicate classes**.

I recommend that you take a look from the following google groups discussion on the gwt-contributors list:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit-contributors/browse_thread/thread/3c768d8d33bfb1dc/5a38aa812c0ac52b

Here is an interesting excerpt:

> If this is all you're interested in, I
>   described a way to make GAE and 
>   GWT-RPC work together "out of the
>   box". Just declare your entities as: 
>   @PersistenceCapable(identityType =
>   IdentityType.APPLICATION,  detachable
>   = "false")  public class MyPojo implements Serializable {  }
>
> and everything will work, but you'll
>   have to manually deal with 
>   re-attachment when sending objects
>   from the client back to the server.

You can use this option, and you will not need a mirror (DTO) class.
You can also try [gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=how-it-works) (former hibernate4gwt), which takes care of some details within the problems of serializing enhanced objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment is correct. JDO replaces instances of Collections with their own implementations, in order to sniff when the object graph changes, I suppose. These implementations are not known by the GWT compiler, so it will not be able to serialize them. This happens often for classes that are composed of otherwise GWT compliant types, but with JDO annotations, especially if some of the object properties are Collections.

For a detailed explanation and a workaround, check out this pretty influential essay on the topic: http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-appengine-and-gwt-now-marriage.html

Comment: JDO does not replace Collections by its own implementations. DataNucleus, for example, has an option to do just that, but the default is to use java.util.* classes so we don't impose on the user to have DataNucleus present on client-side.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. Don't change your object at all, but for the listing do it this way:

```
List<YourCustomObject> secureList=(List<YourCustomObject>)pm.newQuery(query).execute();
return new ArrayList<YourCustomObject>(secureList);
```

The actual problem is not in Serializing the Object... the problem is to Serialize the Collection class which is implemented by Google and is not allowed to Serialize out.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to create two versions of the domain model.

Here are two tips:

Use a String encoded key, not the Appengine Key class.

```
pojo = pm.detachCopy(pojo)
```

...will remove all the JDO enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create separate instances at all, in fact you're better off not doing it. Your JDO objects should be plain POJOs anyway, and should never contain business logic. That's for your business layer, not your persistent objects themselves.

All you need to do is include the source for the annotations you are using and GWT should compile your class just fine. Also, you want to avoid using libraries that GWT can't compile (like things that use reflection, etc.), but in all the projects I've done this has never been a problem.

Comment: The problem isn't that he has business logic in his JDOs, it's the JDO annotations that are causing problems (because GWT does not have access to the source, as you point out).  This is a big problem in GWT+GAE, and I wish Google would articulate a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better format to send objects through GWT is through JSON. In this case from the server a JSON string would be sent which would then have to be parsed in the client. The advantage is that the final Javascript which is rendered in the browser has a smaller size. thus causing the page to load faster.

Secondly to send objects through GWT, the objects should be serializable. This may not be the case for all objects

Thirdly GWT has inbuilt functions to handle JSON... so no issues on the client end

Comment: it's true that sending JSON simplifies the deal, but it's also eliminating a great feature of GWT : having the same object model on both client & server, without the pain of hand writing your serialization.