# SerializationException: type not included in serializable type set

Tags: serialization, gwt, gwt-rpc

In my Google Web Toolkit project, I got the following error:

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type ‘your.class.Type’ was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.

What are the possible causes of this error?

Comment: It means that the return type of the Async call is not serialized. to sort this, implement java.io.seriablizable interface in the return type class.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

GWT keeps track of a set of types which can be serialized and sent to the client. `your.class.Type` apparently was not on this list. Lists like this are stored in `.gwt.rpc` files. These lists are generated, so editing these lists is probably useless. How these lists are generated is a bit unclear, but you can try the following things:

- Make sure `your.class.Type` implements `java.io.Serializable`
- Make sure `your.class.Type` has a public no-args constructor
- Make sure the members of `your.class.Type` do the same
- Check if your program does not contain collections of a non-serializable type, e.g. `ArrayList<Object>`. If such a collection contains `your.class.Type` and is serialized, this error will occur.
- Make `your.class.Type` implement `IsSerializable`. This marker interface was specifically meant for classes that should be sent to the client. This didn't work for me, but my class also implemented `Serializable`, so maybe both interfaces don't work well together.
- Another option is to create a dummy class with `your.class.Type` as a member, and add a method to your RPC interface that gets and returns the dummy. This forces the GWT compiler to add the dummy class and its members to the serialization whitelist.

Comment: amazing! I had not added a default constructor... did not know the purpose of that constructor for Serialized types.... but I my Boss explained it to me after fixing it.... --Thanks again :)

Comment: You are a life saver..
just got some more info at the link http://isolasoftware.it/2011/03/22/gwt-serialization-policy-error/

Comment: Is it possible that this does not work for `enum` types?

Answer (score 4):

I'll also add that if you want to use a nested class, use a static member class. 
I.e.,

```
public class Pojo {
    public static class Insider {
    }
}
```

Nonstatic member classes get the SerializationException in GWT 2.4

Comment: Moving the class outside is another option.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in a RemoteService like this

```
public List<X> getX(...);
```

where X is an interface. The only implementation did conform to the rules, i.e. implements Serializable or IsSerializable, has a default constructor, and all its (non-transient and non-final) fields follow those rules as well.

But I kept getting that SerializationException until I changed the result type from List to X[], so

```
public X[] getX(...);
```

worked. Interestingly, the only argument being a List, Y being an interface, was no problem at all...

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar issue. I had a signature that looked like Collection<X> foo(); I replaced Collection by an implementation (ArrayList) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this problem, and if you per chance are using JPA or Hibernate, this can be a result of trying to return the query object and not creating a new object and copying your relavant fields into that new object.  Check the following out, which I saw in a google group.

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    public static List<Article> getForUser(User user) 
    { 
            List<Article> articles = null; 
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); 
            try 
            { 
                    Query query = pm.newQuery(Article.class); 
                    query.setFilter("email == emailParam"); 
                    query.setOrdering("timeStamp desc"); 
                    query.declareParameters("String emailParam"); 
                    List<Article> results = (List<Article>) query.execute(user.getEmail 
     ()); 
                    articles = new ArrayList<Article>(); 
                    for (Article a : results) 
                    { 
                            a.getEmail(); 
                            articles.add(a); 
                    } 
            } 
            finally 
            { 
                    pm.close(); 
            } 
            return articles; 
    }
```

this helped me out a lot, hopefully it points others in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question is very similar to [what IsSerializable or not in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5379313), see more links to related documentation there.

Answer (score 0):

When your class has JDO annotations, then this fixed it for me (in addition to the points in bspoel's answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826778/1099376