# what IsSerializable or not in GWT?

Tags: serialization, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have this simple object in my GWT project. I cannot send it over the wire. Is it impossible to put a constructor in such a class?

```
public class MceDto implements IsSerializable {
    public MceDto(String uri, String tag) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public String uri;

    public String tag;

    public Date created;
}
```

I checked the *.gwt.rpc policy and the object is not there meaning it is not serializable or something. How can I know beforehand if it is possible to serialize the object?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of GWT are you using?

The `IsSerializable` interface is a vestige of GWT pre-1.4. Have you tried using the Java-standard `java.io.Serializable` marker interface?

See [this GWT FAQ](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server.html#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable) for more.

---

As per the [GWT serialization docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes):

> A user-defined class is serializable if all of the following apply:
>
> 1. It is assignable to [`IsSerializable`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) or [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), either because it directly implements one of these interfaces or because it derives from a superclass that does
> 2. All non-`final`, non-`transient` instance fields are themselves serializable, and
> 3. As of GWT 1.5, it must have a default (zero argument) constructor (with any access modifier) or no constructor at all.

So you must provide a no-arg constructor for your class to be serializable by GWT.